# How do I display the title of a product variant in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm using this to display a WooCommerce product title:

`<?php print $_product->get_title(); ?>`

But it only displays the title of the parent product. How do I display the title of a variant product?

For example, instead of "T-Shirts" I want to display "T-Shirts Size Large".

Answer (score 0):

So, as a staring point, what you want is to get the [`WC_Product_Variation`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variation.html) object. This is pretty straightforward once you have the `variation_id`:

```
$variation = $product->get_child( $variation_id );
```

(If you don't directly have it, you might want to take a look at [`get_available_variations`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variable.html#_get_available_variations))

Then, you could write something as simple as:

```
$attributes = $variation->get_variation_attributes();
echo $product->get_title() . ' Size ' . $attributes['attribute_size'];
```

If you have multiple attributes, you might want to loop through the `$attributes` array instead.

Let me know if you run into any problems,

**EDIT** - Realized the `$attributes` array prefixes `attribute_` before the actual attribute name. It should work now.